# Android Fragment Tab Pager Jerk Issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I am using **ViewPager** with **TabHost** to change fragments with **tab touch/swipe effect**. But the problem is, I am getting Jerk between fragments transition while swipe gesture. What could be the problem? 
 I have used **FragmentTabsPager** class which is used in **Support4Demos** project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved. There was issue in **.xml** file of the **FragmentActivity**. See the layout code below and watch out for comment at the declaration of **LinearLayout**.

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- Replacing layout_height="match_parent" resolved my issue-->
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```